# Tranconductance formula

Tags: amplifier, mosfet-driver, fet

I found two different formula in my course material, feel doubt which one is correct.

Below is the picture of the formula, need your expertise to help me which one the is the correct formula.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: FET or MOSFET? I'm dealing with almost same problems around different formulas myself.

Comment: is for JFET common drain amplifier

Answer (score 1):

\$gm0\$ (for the JFET only) is a transconductance at \$Vgs = 0V\$ and \$I_D = I_{DSS}\$.

That means that \$gm\$ for **|Vgs|< 0** and **Id < Idss** is equal to

$$
gm = gm0 *\left ( 1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_P} \right )= \frac{2I_{DSS}}{|V_P|}*\left ( 1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_T} \right )  
$$

Also notice that \$ V_P = V_{GS(off)} \$

Sometimes we use alternative formula

$$
gm = \frac{2I_{DSS}}{|V_P|}*\sqrt{\frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}}}  
$$

For the MOSFET (enhancement) if we assume that in saturation (active region) the drain current is equal to 
$$
I_D = K*\left ( V_{GS} - V_{P}  \right )^2  
$$ 
and we definde 
$$ 
K = \frac{I_D}{(V_{GS} - V_{P})^2}
$$

the gm is equal to:

$$
gm = 2\sqrt{K*I_D}
$$

Or

$$
gm=2K\left ( V_{GS} - V_{P}  \right )
$$

Comment: What about MOSFET? I haven't found gm0 for MOSFET yet and I don't know if there is one.

Comment: Can be pinch-off voltage (which applies for FET) exchanged with threshold voltage (which applies for MOSFET) - so I can get gm0 for MOSFET?

Comment: @Keno, yes if we replace Idss. for the MOSFET the Idss is equal \$I_{DSS} = K*Vp^2 \$

Comment: Also kept in mind that Idss do not exist in enhancement MOSFET's

Comment: "K" for MOSFETs then equals K=Idss/Ut squared? Where Ut equals threshold voltage.

Comment: Yes, but you have to remember that Idss has no physical meaning in enhancement MOSFET. Because Idss is defined for Vgs=0V. So in this case is just a number. Also this is why we use a different sets of equation for MOSFET and for JFET.

Comment: So, how do you calculate anything if upper statements do not apply for enhancement MOSFET? Unless you are given information as electron mobility parameter, oxide capacitance and W/L-ratio of course, so you can calculate K.

Comment: Welcome to the non-academic world. Simply we do not use K parameter very often. Also in switching application we do not care about the "K". But try to watch this https://youtu.be/eE-8Q0vPUak?t=5m58s and read this https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/06/adem/engin/e77vlsi/lab4/